# Playwright-pytest - Persistent Context for tests - How to create a new tab for each test

Tags: pytest, playwright-python, playwright-test

I wonder if anybody could help?

I'm currently using playwright-pytest for my UI Test Automation.

In the old version you were able to set up persistant context in the contest file such as:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def context(
        browser_type: BrowserType,
        browser_type_launch_args: Dict,
        browser_context_args: Dict
):
    context = browser_type.launch_persistent_context("./foobar", **{
        **browser_type_launch_args,
        **browser_context_args,
        "locale": "en_GB",
    })
    yield context
    context.close()
```

When playwright-pytest was updated you are now forced to use scope="function" which seems to load a new browser for each new test where before it loaded the browser once.
If you change the scope back to session then it errors with:

> ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'browser_context_args' with a 'session' scoped request object, involved factories

Is there a way where I can load the browser just once using the function scope and create a new tab for each test within the test class?

AN example of one of my test classes are as follows:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("context")
class TestImportData:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self, page):
        self.home_page = HomePage(page)
        self.import_data = ImportData(page)
        self.login_page = LoginPage(page)
        self.manage_candidate = ManageCandidate(page)
        self.new_candidate = NewCandidate(page)
        self.approved_timesheets = ApprovedTimesheets(page)
        self.manage_placements = ManagePlacements(page)
        self.manage_companies = ManageCompanies(page)
        self.manage_clients = ManageClients(page)

    @pytest.mark.order(1)
    def test_import_data_page_loads(self, env, page):
        self.login_page.login_to_evertime(env, "SysAdmin")
        self.home_page.click_import_data_button()

    @pytest.mark.order(2)
    def test_import_candidate(self, env, page):
        word = string.ascii_lowercase
        cand_id = (''.join(random.choice(word) for i in range(10)))
        self.import_data.create_candidate_import_file(cand_id)
        self.login_page.login_to_evertime(env, "SysAdmin")
        self.home_page.click_import_data_button()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as my tests are now running so slowly compared to how they were when the scope was session.

Comment: I believe it should be fixed with https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-pytest/pull/85 as `browser_context_args` is now session-scoped